# UITableView, Catching touches on delete?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I wonder if someone would be so kind as to help me out with a query I have regarding deleting rows from a UITableView. I have implemented `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` and now get the [DELETE] button appearing when I swipe on a cell, my question is which method do I need to use to catch a user pressing that button (i.e. [DELETE]).

Also when I do delete a row, can I delete the row from my dataSource and refresh the table. OR  should I delete the row from the dataSource and then call some other method on the tableView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I was after, the callback for the swipe and the callback when the user selects [DELETE].

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Swipe ...");
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Delete Pressed.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete from the data source and call reloadData on the table. Or do you have like a million rows in the table?

Comment: About 20 rows and thats capped so doing the delete and reload should be fine, I just wanted to make sure I was not missing a better way. I guess using one of UITableViews methods is more useful like you say with millions of rows, or if you want the delete to be animated.

Comment: reloadData works just fine even with thousands of rows, so on 20 rows you should be OK.